# Is it possible to access the domain name for an Elastic Beanstalk application in the config file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

Right now I have a config file that specifies commands to run when deploying my Elastic Beanstalk application. One of the commands uses certbot to setup a SSL certificate in Nginx. Here's an example:

```
container_commands:
  01run_certbot:
    command: |
      curl -O https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
      chmod +x certbot-auto
      sudo mv certbot-auto /usr/bin/certbot-auto

  02install_certs:
    command: |
      certbot-auto --verbose --nginx -m admin@someemail.com -n --agree-tos --domains my-app-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com --debug

  03restart_nginx:
    command: "service nginx restart"
```

What I would like to do is pass the cname of the application to the certbot-auto program instead of hardcoding it into the config file itself. Is this possible?

Comment: You shouldn't be requesting an SSL Certificate for a domain you don't own (elasticbeanstalk.com). You should be assigning a custom domain name to your EB application, and then requesting an SSL certificate for that custom domain. If you are using a load balancer in your EB environment then it would be much easier to use the AWS ACM service for a free SSL certificate.

Comment: That does sound like a better solution. I was trying to be cheap and not place a load balancer in front of the instances. But I will use a domain the I own. Thanks